# Boost Geometry: assertion_failed error C++

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-geometry

I have the following header file in order to use boost geometry types:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;
using namespace detail::assign;

typedef model::d2::point_xy<double> point_xy;
typedef model::polygon<point_xy> polygon;
typedef model::multi_polygon<polygon> multi_polygon;
typedef model::box<point_xy> box;
```

When compiling a file that attempts to use these types, I get a massive compiler error:

```
In file included from src/geometry.cpp:11:
In file included from src/../include/geometry.hpp:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/coordinate_dimension.hpp:23:
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/point_type.hpp:45:5: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:454:51: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG'
#   define BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG( c, msg, types_ ) \
                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:440:9: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG_IMPL'
        boost::mpl::assertion_failed<(c)>( BOOST_PP_CAT(mpl_assert_arg,counter)::assert_arg() ) \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:60:58: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT'
#   define BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT(T, expr) enum { expr }
                                                         ^~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/point_type.hpp:65:30: note: in instantiation of template class
      'boost::geometry::traits::point_type<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >' requested here
            typename traits::point_type<Geometry>::type
                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/coordinate_type.hpp:58:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::core_dispatch::point_type<void,
      std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >' requested here
    typedef typename point_type<GeometryTag, Geometry>::type point_type;
                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/coordinate_type.hpp:88:37: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::core_dispatch::coordinate_type<void,
      std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >' requested here
    typedef typename core_dispatch::coordinate_type
                                    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/access.hpp:269:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::coordinate_type<std::__1::vector<float,
      std::__1::allocator<float> > >' requested here
inline typename coordinate_type<Geometry>::type get(Geometry const& geometry
                ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/convert_point_to_point.hpp:42:74: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template
      'get' [with Dimension = 0, Geometry = std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >]
        set<Dimension>(destination, boost::numeric_cast<coordinate_type>(get<Dimension>(source)));
                                                                         ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/convert_point_to_point.hpp:58:76: note: (skipping 3 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0
      to see all)
    point_to_point<Source, Destination, 0, dimension<Destination>::value>::apply(source, destination);
                                                                           ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/append.hpp:129:45: note: in instantiation of member function
      'boost::geometry::detail::append::append_range<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>,
      true, true, vector, allocator>, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float,
      std::__1::allocator<float> > > > >::apply' requested here
            append_range<ring_type, Range>::apply(
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/append.hpp:296:51: note: in instantiation of member function
      'boost::geometry::detail::append::range_to_polygon<boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double,
      boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::vector, std::allocator, std::allocator>, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float,
      std::__1::allocator<float> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > > > >::apply' requested here
        dispatch::append<Geometry, RangeOrPoint>::apply(geometry,
                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/append.hpp:371:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'boost::geometry::resolve_variant::append<boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>,
      true, true, std::vector, std::vector, std::allocator, std::allocator> >::apply<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > > > >' requested here
                   ::apply(geometry, range_or_point, ring_index, multi_index);
                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/assign.hpp:75:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'boost::geometry::append<boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true,
      std::vector, std::vector, std::allocator, std::allocator>, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > > > >' requested here
    geometry::append(geometry, range, -1, 0);
              ^
src/geometry.cpp:213:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'boost::geometry::assign_points<boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true,
      std::vector, std::vector, std::allocator, std::allocator>, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > > > >' requested here
    assign_points(poly, shape.border);
    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:83:5: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::mpl::failed
      ************(boost::geometry::traits::point_type<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >
      >::NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_POINT_TYPE::************)(types<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >)' to 'typename assert<false>::type'
      (aka 'mpl_::assert<false>') for 1st argument
int assertion_failed( typename assert<C>::type );
    ^
In file included from src/geometry.cpp:11:
In file included from src/../include/geometry.hpp:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:28:
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/core/coordinate_type.hpp:43:5: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:454:51: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG'
#   define BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG( c, msg, types_ ) \
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639081/c-boost-geometry-error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-assertion-failed) post in which they did not register tuples - however, I am not using tuples or any special kind of point - I am just attempting to use the built in geometry types. Why is this error still occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the code posted is not a problem per se: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17db021f3236d1a0).

So,there must be something else interfering. I have three hunches:

1. It's somewhere else in your code that you didn't post. The cause of the error is in `../src/geometry.cpp` (not Boost library):

   ```
   assign_points(poly, shape.border);
   ```

   That gives you good ideas on how to reduce to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
2. You have preprocessor issues. Try pre-processing your sources and see whether any of the code appearing in the error messages looks suspect.

   A classical example of this would be if some other included header defines tokens like `#define min(a,b) ...` or other commonly used words.

   > Side note: this is about code-hygiene. A related note is the appearance of `using namespace` in your shown code snippet. This just begs namespace collisions or unintended effects.
3. Slightly related: the source of the interference could have to do with pre-compiled headers. Try disabling those or making sure you know what is in the PCH header (especially on MSVC (commonly using `stdafx.h`) precompiled headers have some potentially surprising effects)

### UPDATE

I think I spotted it: the offending code at src/geometry.cpp:213:5 calls:

```
assign_points(poly, shape.border);
```

With the types: `poly` is

```
boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::vector, std::allocator, std::allocator>,
```

That's the `polygon` typedef you show above. But `shape.border` is:

```
std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float>>>>>
```

That's just `vector<std::vector<float> >`. That's not a supported Geometry.

Comment: Added an update, showing that you are assigning from an incompatible `shape.border` type